# I got a trio input function from a friend and it's trying to use trio.lowleve.FdStream, however I can't find it

Tags: python, python-trio

I'm getting this error: AttributeError: module 'trio.lowlevel' has no attribute 'FdStream'. FdStream isn't in the trio code on git nor in my installation. Is there an alternative to this, or is there a different version I did't find?

Comment: Are you sure you're running the latest version of trio?

Comment: As for FdStream not being in trio git?
https://github.com/python-trio/trio/blob/master/trio/lowlevel.py#L62

Comment: Also, are you running Windows? FdStream is part of the Unix specific API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That attribute is only available on non-Windows platforms. If your friend made the function compatible with only Linux/macos, you will need to run the function on a Posix platform as well.